# Multiselect in PrimeNG multi select showing empty values

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, multi-select

I have a multiselect component:

```
<p-multiSelect class="multiple-select" display="chip" [options]="allTags" name="selectedTags" [(ngModel)]="selectedTags" optionLabel="tag" optionValue="tag"></p-multiSelect>
```

A single tag in the allTags array:

```
{ tag: 'someTag' }
```

And the selectedTags array contains strings. when adding tags, it works perfectly. The issue arises when I want to preselect some tags.

```
  preselectTags(tags: string[]) {
    tags.map(x => this.selectedTags.push(x));

  }
```

Ive tried forEach, and plain re assigning instead of array.map but every time I see something like this:

[image]

Console.logging the selectedTags after filling it returns an array of correct strings. what am i doing wrong?

PS. thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, I suppose that **selectedTags** array should have the same structure as **allTags** so, when you make a push you have to build that structure.

```
preselectTags(tags: string[]) {
   tags.map(x => this.selectedTags.push({val:x}));
}
```

Hope you helpfully, if don't, please give the prints of each array structure.
Regards

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the answer. In the docs, and I have seen in multiple other instances too, that allTags are objects; `{ tag: 'someTag'}`, and the array binded to it is an array of string. `['tag1, 'tag2', 'tag3']`. Like I said, it works perfectly when I want to **add** gifts, the issue arrises when I when to **edit** them, which forces me to preselect the values. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a find of the options in order to filter out unwanted items/selecting the tags..

So depending on what the tags array is, you could loop over them, or try:

```
preselectTags(tags: string[]) {

  this.selectedTags = tags.map(x => this.allTags.find(y => y.val === x.val));
}
```

It would be easier to help with the structure of said arrays....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already receive the options I want, and they are generated from the allTags array themselves.  `tags.map(x => this.selectedTags.push(x));` is where I do that. Like I said, if I take the mapped 'selectedTags' value, and add them to the variable initially, like `selectedTags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] `, it works. and when I console.log the result of my above code, the the array is identical, but no idea why that doesn't work too.